# mysql user has no privileges. \s shows I am logged in correctly. Error messages refer to a user of ''@localhost

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite

The non-root user in my mysql has no privileges once logged in, despite what the configuration is saying.

I can log into mysql with root, and with my own account.

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+-------+------------------+
| user  | host             |
+-------+------------------+
| jake  | %                |
| root  | 127.0.0.1        |
| root  | ::1
+--------------------------+
```

And when I log in as my own user, and run the server status, it shows that I'm logged in as my own user from localhost.

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      85
Current database:   
Current user:       jake@localhost
```

but when I try to do anything:

```
mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

I get an error message that indicates my username is NULL. This seems impossible.

This non-root user has every known global privilege, which I've confirmed with phpmyadmin, which also works as long as I log in as root.

Why does the error message indicate a NULL username, which conflicts with the information returned by \s command?

**Update:** I just checked another non-root user, and this account is behaving as expected. The problem is apparently limited to just the account which matches my macos account.

I'm on Yosemite, Mysql-5.5.38.

Comment: Maybe there are entries in the `db` table that disallow the user to use the mysql db.

Comment: to which table are you referring? according to everything I've checked, the user should have every possible access...

Comment: I refere to the db table in schema mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1).

There was an anonymous user defined for localhost, that was masking my actual username.